# Hosting C++ application on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have seen that Google App Engine does support yet C++ code. Can I run a **C++ application** (.exe) on **Google Compute Engine** within an Apache web server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work just fine. Please note, though, that we currently only support linux based operating systems.  If (as the `.exe` extension suggests) you have C++ code compiled for windows, you may need to recompile or even rewrite parts of it if it's not compatible with Linux.

Comment: Thank you Benson for the reply.